# Magento 2 - How to create a Block for back-end/adminhtml?

Tags: magento2, blocks, adminhtml

I am using a module like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="header.container">
        <container name="header.containertwo" as="header_containertwo" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="header-mini-container" after="header.panel.wrapper"/>
    </referenceContainer>
<referenceContainer name="header.containertwo">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="header.mini.container" template="Vendor_Module::test.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
</page>
```

At this point test.phtml is just hard coded content.

test.phtml:

```
<div>
Content is here but I need to content to be read from a Block created in the back-end instead
</div>
```

I want to create a block for my `test.phtml` where i able to read/use my custom block.
How can I create a block for `test.phtml`.?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create the `adminhtml` page with block by following below code

```
<referenceContainer name="header.containertwo">
    <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\CustomBlock" name="Overview" template="Vendor_Module::test.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```

And create the block.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template;

class CustomBlock extends Template
{

    public function greet()
    {
        return 'Hello world';
    }

}
```

in `test.phtml` you can access the block like.

```
<h2> Hello i'm custom </h2>
<p><?php echo $block->greet(); ?></p>
```

Remove the cache and check.

[Reference](https://github.com/Tym17/Magento2-Admin-Module-Sample)

Comment: What i mean is login into mymagesite/admin... and going into content/blocks and creating one there

Comment: I confused, give me some information.

Comment: I just want the module .phtml file to read the data from something I've added on the login backend

Comment: In admin create a CMS block, and use the below code with block id in .phtml {{block class="Magento\\Cms\\Block\\Block" block_id="block_identifier"}}